# PDE $au_{xx} +2bu_{xy}+cu_{yy}$ into canonical form

Tags: partial-differential-equations, substitution, canonical-transformation

I am looking for the right substitution, to transform the pde $au_{xx} +2bu_{xy}+cu_{yy}=f$ with $ac \gt b^2$ into the canonical form $\nabla^2U(\hat x,\hat y)=F(\hat x,\hat y)$ where $\nabla^2$ is the laplace-operator. Using the linear substituion $\begin{pmatrix}\hat x \\ \hat y \end{pmatrix}=M\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$

Would appreciate any hint/help

Answer (score 1):

After the change of variables

$$
r = m_1 x + m_2 y\\
s = m_3 x + m_4 y
$$

we got

$$
(am_3^2+m_4(2bm_3+c m_4))u_{ss}+2(am_1 m_3+b(m_2 m_3+m_1m_4)+cm_2m_4)u_{rs}+(am_1^2+2bm_1m_2+c m_2^2)u_{rr}=0
$$

I hope this helps.

Comment: Fixing typos...

Comment: May I ask how you came to the $=0$ at the end ? When I substitute, I get something like $am{_3}^2u_{ss} +b(m_2m_3 +m_1m_4) u_{r,s}+{am_1}^2u_{rr}=F$

Comment: Now the coordinates change is OK. I don't include the developments because are lengthly.